# How calling a column in a function is different from calling a column outside in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"Age":[11,12,14,15,np.NaN,np.NaN],"Class":[10,11,10,11,9,9]})
df

def impute_age(cols):
    Age = cols[0]
    Class = cols[1]

    if np.isnan(Age):

        if Class == 10:
            return 11

        elif Class == 11:
            return 12

        else:
            return 9

    else:
        return Age

df.apply(impute_age,axis=1)
```

Here in this impute_age function, it called first row as cols[0],but if we call a column of a dataframe outside the funcion by using cols[0], it will show error because we have to specify the column name. Why?

Comment: Outside your function `cols` is not defined.

Comment: When you use `df.apply(impute_age, axis=1)` - the impute_age function is applied along the columns - i.e. for every row, a new column is created. Which means that you are applying the `impute_age` function to every single row

Comment: You want to read about namespaces and variable scopes. You can find more about this on https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If check `print(cols)` it return each row of DataFrame like Series, so if want select by position use `iat`:

```
def impute_age(cols):
    print (cols)
    Age = cols.iat[0]
    Class = cols.iat[1]
    if np.isnan(Age):

        if Class == 10:
            return 11

        elif Class == 11:
            return 12

        else:
            return 9

    else:
        return Age
```

Or select by column name:

```
def impute_age(cols):
    print (cols)
    Age = cols['Age']
    Class = cols['Class']
    if np.isnan(Age):

        if Class == 10:
            return 11

        elif Class == 11:
            return 12

        else:
            return 9

    else:
        return Age
```

---

```
df = df.apply(impute_age,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [DataFrame.apply documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

> Objects passed to the function are Series objects [...]

This means that what's passed to impute_age is a Series, not the complete DataFrame. i.e. the function is not applied to `df` but to `df.loc[i]` (for each possible i): If you print `df.loc[0][0]` you'll get the `Age` value of the first row.